# jQuery / Javascript replace function only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as such

```
<button id="toggle_photo">
<span id="photo_text">Hide Photos (1)</span>
<img class="icon" alt="Photos" src="/img/photos-16.png">
</button>
```

And jQuery / Javascript to change the text upon clicking

```
$('#toggle_photo').click(function(){
    var text = $('#photo_text').text();
    $('#photo_text').text(
      text.match(/Hide Photos/) ? text.replace("Hide", "Show") : text.replace("Show", "Hide"));
    $('.photo_frame').toggle('slow');
  });
```

This works the first time the button is clicked and the button text changed from `Hide Photo (1)` to `Show Photo (1)`. Next, the button html is replaced with new text via an AJAX call, new contents are the same except perhaps for the count, so it might show this instead

```
<button id="toggle_photo">
<span id="photo_text">Hide Photos (3)</span>
<img class="icon" alt="Photos" src="/img/photos-16.png">
</button>
```

However, this time the element didn't trigger a click event, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself:

> Next, the button html is **replaced** with new text via an AJAX call...

You are removing the current element and adding a new one. The elements might be of the same type and have the same ID, but they are still different elements.

You either have to bind the event handler again after you changed the HTML, or you use [`.live()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the event handler.

*Edit:* I'm actually not sure whether you replace the whole button or just its contents. But I assume this is the problem. If this does not help, you have to be more specific and also post the function which replaces the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of the `live` or `delegate` methods, good to know. Actually, the entire button's content got replaced, not just `<span id="photo_text...`.

Comment: Only the content or also the button itself?

Comment: The button itself also. I'm trying to get `delegate` syntax working properly, the click event is not triggering at all now, this is what I have `$('#toggle_photo').delegate('button', 'click', function(){...`

Comment: `#toggle_photo` is the button itself. It has no descendant `button`. You have to bind this handler to some *ancestor* of `#toggle_photo`. E.g. `$('#someAncestor').delegate('#toggle_photo', 'click',...);` Remember that the button is removed. If you remove it, also the event handlers are removed. The new button is not the same. So using `delegate` on the button itself does not make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out too and bound it to an ancestor and it works. Now I need to make sure it doesn't blindly apply to other buttons I might add later.

Comment: If you use the id of the button `.delegate('#toggle_photo',...` then there will be no problems...